# How can i have the COMPLETE Outtput of the summary-function of an intercept onlymodel (gls-function) in R?

Tags: r, output, summary, nlme, sink

right now I'm computing a multilevel Model in RStudio and would like to store my outputs. But I can't find any working solution for this. I used already the sink-function. The problem is that the sink function just stores the first of three outputs the summaryfunction is presenting. When i create tables than I lose the first of three outputs.

I would like to export the summary as a picture or better as text.

The code is the following:

```
interceptOnly_meaning <-gls(meaningfulness ~ 1, data = data, method =
"ML")
summary(interceptOnly_meaning)
```

I am really happy and thankful for any help.

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: `saveRDS()` will save any kind of object to disk.

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks for your proposal. I forgot to write in the Text that i would like to have the output as an image or an pdf format. Do you have any idea to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can set up a Rmd document which will allow you among other things to save it as a PDF document: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html

Comment: Thank you so much Phil! Now i understood the knit function! Thank you very much! :)